# @font-face in Rails 4.0 with Sass URL not found for custom fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, ruby-on-rails-4, font-face

In my Rails project I am trying to use custom fonts. There are lots of answers related to this question, like this answer which didn't help, I edited `development.rb`:

```
# Add the fonts path
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')

# Precompile additional assets
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

still it shows `No route matches [GET] "/assets/chalkduster-webfont.woff"`

I set me `url` like:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'chalkdusterregular';
    src: url('chalkduster-webfont.eot');
    src:url('chalkduster-webfont.svg#chalkdusterregular') format('svg'), 
    url('chalkduster-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('chalkduster-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('chalkduster-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

I tried `font_path('')` within source and also `font-url()` it never works. :(

Answer (score 32):

Try `asset-url()`. Works for me.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'chalkdusterregular';
    src: asset-url('chalkduster-webfont.eot');
    src: asset-url('chalkduster-webfont.svg#chalkdusterregular') format('svg'), 
         asset-url('chalkduster-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         asset-url('chalkduster-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         asset-url('chalkduster-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Also, I only add the fonts path and precompile additional assets in config/environments/production.rb

```
# Add the fonts path
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')

# Precompile additional assets
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

Doesn't need to be added to config/environments/development.rb as `asset-url` works a little magic.

Comment: Looks like you can even use `font-url('font_name')` instead of `asset-url('font_name', font)`

Comment: For  me, `font-url` doesn't work (links to /fonts/file.ext), while `asset-url` works (links to /assets/file.ext)

Comment: for me it worked with *.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf on rails 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative more easy to implement not required imports and this is:
You can convert your font file on a base 64 text.
Make sure you check the choice Base64 encode 
[image]

then click on convert and download the .zip file that generate the page.
Inside the .zip file open de .css and you see the code you need.
[image]

---

i try to implement the solution of the jverban but for me, doesn't works.

> Then i found a tuto, where explain two ways todo it, [click for open the tuto](https://gist.github.com/anotheruiguy/7379570)

and i try the second solution (The way of the hacker). and the only to do is move the fonts folder inside the app/assets/stylesheets. (i supuose you put all of you fonts inside a folder named fonts)

then in the css file o scss, you can do it with this code.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GoodDDC';
    src: url(asset_path("fonts/GOODDC.ttf"));
}
```

asset_path reference on rails the folder `app/assets/stylesheets`

the tree folder look like

```
app/assets/stylesheets/fonts/yourfont.ttf (wof, etc)
```