# Ruby on Rails Bootstrap Glyphicons not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have added bootstrap to my site. Here is the structure I am using. (I cannot whatsoever remove the bootstrap.css file since it I modified it to my liking).

```
>app
>>assets
>>>fonts
>>>>4 glypicons icon files.
>>>images
>>>>N/A
>>>javascripts
>>>>Bootstrap.js (Jquery is installed in a gem)
>>>stylesheets
>>>>Bootstrap.css
```

Everything is imported correctly, but the issue is that the glyphicons arent working and I need them!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

November 2015 EDIT: I would recommend this gem: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass It is actively maintained by the Bootstrap community and works really well with Ruby on Rails.

I was having a very similar issue as you but I figure it out! Find this part in your bootstrap.css file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

and replace `../fonts/` with `/assets`. This is what your final code will look like.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: No problem. Just so you know, the same thing applies with font awesome. Just replace the ../dir/ with /assets!

Comment: If you're using the non-compiled Less or Sass version, you can set the  `$icon-font-path: "/assets/"` variable.

Comment: I followed a better solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962775/bootstrap-3rails-4-certain-glyphicons-not-working/25098941#25098941

Comment: Odd, since my files are in /assets/fonts/ but it works

Comment: I tried with suggested solution and it did not work for me, here is a generic solution that helps you troubleshoot any problem related to this you might have http://stackoverflow.com/a/40898227/1197775

Answer (score 45):

If you are using bootstrap-sass and you have this issue try to import bootstrap like this in one of your scss files. If you use sass, just convert the syntax:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap-sass, but I don't have any sass files other than scss.  Where do I put this?  It doesn't work in the scss files.

Comment: I figured it out.  They needed to be in quotations with semicolons at the end of the lines.  I've noticed some behavioural change in the site after this.

Comment: @Confusion It is mentioned over here that it should be imported for the icons to work: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Dang. Yeah, this was my problem. That was pretty dumb of me too, since `bootstrap-sass`'s documentation [clearly states](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails) that you need to import `bootstrap-sprockets` before `boostrap`, and I even remember reading that, but for some reason I didn't have that in my code. Oh well... live and learn I guess.

Answer (score 36):

**For me as a `twitter-bootstrap-rails` user:**

Thanks to take's post @ GitHub

Adding this:

```
/* Override Bootstrap 3 font locations */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

to my `application.css` fixed the issue.

Hope to be helpful.

Comment: Worked for me in Rails 4, thanks. There is a comment in bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less, to enable glyphicons, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Thanks!! I've been struggling with that for hours

Comment: This also worked for me on localhost but not on Heroku. I found that the comment referred to by @sadfuzzy above (in (for me): /app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css) held the key to this working. For Font Awesome you use: "=require twitter-bootstrap-static/fontawesome" and for Glyphicons you use: "=require twitter-bootstrap-static/sprites".

Comment: Per the twitter-bootsrap-rails docs, to enable Glyphicons, add the following to the _bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less_ file:

 `@glyphiconsEotPath: font-url("glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
@glyphiconsEotPath_iefix: font-url("glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix");
@glyphiconsWoffPath: font-url("glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff");
@glyphiconsTtfPath: font-url("glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf");
@glyphiconsSvgPath: font-url("glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular");

@import "twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons.less";`

Answer (score 30):

I was also struggling to make boostrap3 glyphicon work in rails 4.
I solved it by adding

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'));
  src: url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'), url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')) format('woff'), url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')) format('truetype'), url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')) format('svg');
}`
```

to *application.css.scss* file
and

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/fonts"
```

to application.rb file.

Comment: I personally like this answer as I am unable to modify my bootstrap css file

Comment: Thanks! It works finally after hours of researching T.T

Answer (score 10):

I think you might be having a problem with the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

You want to change `bootstrap.css` to `bootstrap.css.scss` and then replace where it uses

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

with [`font-path`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) (look at section 2.3.2 - CSS and Sass)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
    font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Also in your `config/environments/production.rb`

```
# Precompile additional assets
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

In your `config/application.rb`

```
# Add the fonts path
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

Check out another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313287/font-face-at-rails-4-0-with-sass-url-not-found-for-custom-fonts) for a similar problem

Hope this helps

Comment: Will I have to change it to scss? Can I leave it as a css file?

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. I get an error saying that there was invalid css. It expected a { but instead got a ("

Comment: Did you change it to `bootstrap.css.scss`? `font-path` only works in SASS

Comment: Yes, I did. I will try again.

Comment: I tried again and no error! I dont get what to do for the second half. On my local machine I am running in development mode.

Comment: For the second half, it's there for whenever you deploy it to a server, so you don't get an error when you go live on production, but it works now?

Comment: The error is gone, but there is no glyphicon, just some % signs.

Comment: I updated the answer, also if you look at the console using the [chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console), and paste any errors or issues that come up, that might be helpful

Comment: This is the error log from chrome. I updated everything and its still not working! Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: @user2262149 This is a highly ineffective since you can pretty much do it in css. Check my answer above.

Comment: Thanks, I used to do it that way but when I pushed it to production, it couldn't find that address, because rails adds a hash to the each asset when adds a fingerprint (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) so the solution above worked for me in production, but thanks for the comment and glad your solution worked!

Comment: Worked right away, and looks cleaner than other solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap 3 icons look like this:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-right"></i>
```

whereas Bootstrap 2 looked like this:

```
<i class="icon-indent-right"></i>
```

If the code you are using isn't up to date (check for a b3 branch), then you may have to fork and change the icon names your self.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently Chrome has been broken for months re this issue.

This worked for me when I put it in the top of my customization_css.css.scss file

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding `@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");` worked for me. Do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('<%= asset_path("glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot") %>');
  src: url('<%= asset_path("glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") %>') format('embedded-opentype'), url('<%= asset_path("glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") %>') format('woff2'), url('<%= asset_path("glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") %>') format('woff'), url('<%= asset_path("glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") %>') format('truetype'), url('<%= asset_path("glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") %>') format('svg');
}
```

You just need to convert your your_css.css file to your_css.css.erb

Comment: yeah, since asset's path on production includes hash digest. this should be the right answer even in the time this question was asked. it feels like the code in the gem never supposed to work

Comment: My asset path was different due to a yarn install of bootstrap: ```src: url('<%= asset_path("bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot") %>');```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy all the bootstrap font files to public/fonts and it will work. No need for imports or changes in the application.rb.

Answer (score 2):

I tried with suggested solution and it did not work for me, here is a [generic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40898227/1197775) that helps you troubleshoot any problem related to this you might have.

Here is the resulting font face definition with bootstrap-sass:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: asset-url('bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src:
    asset-url('bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    asset-url('bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
    asset-url('bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    asset-url('bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working), there's a bug with the Bootstrap customizer that messes up the glyphicon fonts. I had the same issue, but I was able to fix it by downloading the entirety of bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/, and then copying the font files to the correct location.

Comment: Well I have customized the bootstrap.css file a lot! I dont want to erase any work that has been done so far. Where exactly would the correct files be?

Comment: You wouldn't have to touch the css file at all. In order for me to fix my problem, I downloaded bootstrap-3.0.2-dist.zip, copied everything from the dist/fonts folder, and replaced the fonts I had added to my project.

Comment: I created my project with `bootstrap-sass` and the fonts weren't working for me. Downloaded the bootstrap zip and just copied the fonts across to the `\stylesheets\fonts\bootstrap` folder and all was well. Also needed to change my `config.rb` file as my site wasn't in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4, with sass, Bootstrap 3.2.0, and the bootstrap-sass gem use:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/theme";
```

Answer (score 0):

When i use bootstrap in my rails apps i use the bootstrap-sass gem.

https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass

You can override it. Simply import it as the docs explain. Then Import or paste your modified files.

In a php project, the glyph weren't working, i download the classic bootstrap zip and i extracted the glyph files to replace them in the project. In my memories the bug appears when you generate a custom bootstrap style from their site (the source of the bug can be wrong).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my index.html.slim file, I replaced `span.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar` with `span.fa.fa-calendar` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.compile = true
```

And add fonts to precompile list

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.eot *.svg *.ttf *.woff *.woff2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used this `<i class="icon-plus"></i>`, which I took from oficcial site of Bootstrap and didn't see anything. But instead, it is neccessary to use this `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have the glyphicons files in `app/assets/fonts` (if you don't, you can download them from the [`bootstrap-saas repo`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/assets/fonts/bootstrap)), create `app/assets/stylesheets/fonts.scss` and add the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: font-url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: font-url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  font-url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
  font-url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  font-url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```