# Rails glyphicons path in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

For my (Bootstrap 3.2.0, rails 4.0.8, ruby 2.1.2) application I get an error message (in the chrome console)

> http://example.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 404 (Not Found) jquery.js?body=1:3581

I fixed similar error messages for css stylesheets using the method in [Ruby on Rails Bootstrap Glyphicons not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255711/ruby-on-rails-bootstrap-glyphicons-not-working)
i.e. by changing the font path from /fonts to /assets

How would I fix the glyphicon path for the javascript?

(Glyphicons seem to display just fine, and I am not sure what effect this error would have)

Comment: what path are you using for your fonts?

Comment: The same as above with "fonts" repleaced by "assets", i.e. http://example.com/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff