# DataTables not displaying bootstrap glyhpicons in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, datatables-1.10

Since I give up adding DataTables 1.10.8 using Rails-assets or Bower in my Rails 4 project, I added the component directly in `/vendor/assets/DataTables` directory and edited in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require select2
//= require datatables  // This
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and application.css.scss

```
*= require_self
 *= require select2
 *= require datatables  // This
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

To test that DataTables I just enter to one my forms and with the Chrome console, I set a bootstrap class to a table, and converted to a DataTable with this:

```
$('table').DataTable( {
    dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
    buttons: {
        name: 'primary',
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel' ]
    }
} );
```

Apparently it works, but there's something missing, those tiny icons in the sort headers.

[image]

Note: I included a customized download from the DataTables website.

**Update:**
Apparently I have a problem with the glyphicons, some font is missing or something. I'm currently using the `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'`

Answer (score 0):

- Did you copy over the images into the asset folder? You will need to copy over the "vendor/assets/images/dataTables/{sort_asc.png|sort_both.png|sort_desc.png" files
- You should try avoiding adding dataTable to all tables **$('table')**, does that, either bind it to a class **(".dt")** or id **("#dt")**
- The correct API is **$('table').dataTable({})**. Note the small case. **"DataTable"** returns the api object and not the DataTable object. But then obviously, It still works!

Ensure the application.js files has

```
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/{3 OR 2}/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

And these files should be also placed within vendor/assets folder

Btw, did you try using the [jquery-datatables-rails](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails) gem?

Add the following to your Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 3.3.0'
```

Run the following command in your project folder

```
rails generate jquery:datatables:install bootstrap2
```

or if you prefer bootstrap3

Ensure you add your Extra's in the application.js and css files, for e.g.

```
//= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.tableTools
```

Should be present in your application.js file and similarly your application.css should have the following:

```
 *= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.tableTools
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it. About jQuery-datatables-rails gem i was planning to use it, however, after watching the sources in its github directory i figure out that its using an 1.10.7, and I'm using the most recent version 1.10.8 of DataTables. Apparenty, buttons extension is not included

Comment: Mmmm... I think this won't work. `*= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.tableTools ` means that you're assuming that I'm using tableTools, which is not the case. That is being deprecated. I also get the generated download file from the DataTables site.

Comment: The "tableTools" is what has become "Buttons" extension. Other then "ColViz" extension tableTools has everything Buttons provides.

Comment: yes, and I also included that in my download for the HTML5 buttons export... but the excel button doesn't work either :(

Comment: I haven't checked the new "Button" extension, but if it's the same code as tableTools, then you will need to ensure you are serving "/assets/dataTables/extras/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" file.

Comment: Just looked into the plugin extension documentation. Looks like the new Button plugin for excel does not work in Safari. Also, if you are using the excelhtml5, then you need https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ also in your project

Comment: Not surprising. Safari is so delayed in support of HTML5. Perhaps is intentional because Apple don't want people to access to the iOS filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that fixed was downloading a bootstrap package and copy the fonts into a fonts folder in vendor directory, and add the following described on this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20297523/598070

Answer (score 0):

I simply copied the images to `app/assets/images` and created a workaround route for these specific image files like this:

```
 get '/assets/plugins/datatables/images/:name.:ext', to: redirect('/assets/%{name}.%{ext}'), constraints: { name: /.+/, ext: /(jpg|png|gif)/ }
```

Works fine with `jquery-datatables-rails (3.4.0)` and rails `5.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the icon is not shown is due to fonts. `Glyphicons` is not loaded.

I resolved with following code.

```
    diff --git a/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.scss b/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.scss
    index 2f5a9f9..0bbbcc8 100644
    --- a/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.scss
    +++ b/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.scss
    @@ -4,6 +4,7 @@
       Use Font Awesome icons (default)
       To use Glyphicons sprites instead of Font Awesome, replace with "require twitter-bootstrap-static/sprites"
       =require twitter-bootstrap-static/fontawesome
    +  =require twitter-bootstrap-static/sprites
       */
     .alert-notice {
       color: #3c763d;
```