# Bootstrap Glyphicons not working on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glyphicons

In my Rails 5 app, I have this in my `application.sass` file...

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap-sass-official
 ...
 */

 @font-face
   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings'
   src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot')
   src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg')
```

...as per the advice in [Ruby on Rails Bootstrap Glyphicons not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255711/ruby-on-rails-bootstrap-glyphicons-not-working).  I get this error in my Chrome console: `Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff`, `etc..` for the various font formats.

Do I need to put anything into my Rails assets `fonts` folder?  If so, what specifically?  Thanks so much for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

As the application is Rails 5, better way - place your fonts in the folder `app/assets/fonts`.

If you want to place them outside `fonts` folder, you'll need to add the following configuration:

`config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/`

And then can use urls as your mentioned

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: @Matt glad to help! The SO thanks - marked as answer answer if it works ;)

Comment: Do you know if there were any differences in Rails 4 in working with glyphicons?

Comment: @Matt as I know in rails 4 you don't have font folder but you can create it and update the asset pipeline. Fix is pretty simple. Open your project config file, located at `config/application.rb` and add the following line within your Application class: `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")`