# Rails 4.1 - ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/....ttf") - @font-face issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, font-face

I feel like I tried all solutions I found here and on some blogs but something is still wrong and I have no idea what.

My error:

```
...
Started GET "/fonts/amaze.ttf" for 83.9.18.180 at 2014-11-26 09:10:21 +0000
...
app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/amaze.ttf"):
...
```

Of course on localhost it isn't working either.

I am using rails 4.1.1

My font is located in:

```
assets/fonts/amaze.ttf
```

I even relocated it to check if it would work: assets/amaze.ttf -it wasn't.

My current solution in application.css.scss file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Amaze';
  src: font-url('amaze.ttf');
}

.amaze {
  font-family: 'Amaze';
}
```

I tried some configuration in application.rb but had no effect:

```
config.assets.enabled = true  
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"  
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
```

Do I even have to configure anything in application or development/production files?

---

EDIT

### (kind of) FIXED a PROBLEM

The problem was that I had a broken font...

more details:
I had font from here http://fontzone.net/download/amaze-normal
and it was broken (I mean not exactly broken, it worked on linux, but not with font-face, no idea why, if it's worth anyone's efforts give it a try to figure out what was the issue)

I tried another font from another source:
http://www.fontcubes.com/Amaze.font

and it worked! yey! *-*

---

EDIT

I had similar issue with more fonts (both otf and ttf) so I would say problem is still open ;p

Comment: The font url helper is actually named `font_url` - notice the underscore instead of the dash sign.

Comment: OK, I changed it. Still the same. Thank you for try. I will keep on digging.

Answer (score 20):

#### Utilize the Asset Pipeline or move your `fonts` to the `public` directory.

Your problem here is that the path `/fonts/amaze.ttf` is not hitting the Rails Asset Pipeline. It would need to be prefaced with `/assets` in order to use the Asset Pipeline, like `/assets/fonts/amaze.ttf` or `/assets/amaze.ttf`.

You have two main options here:

1. **Update the path request:**

   So use `/assets/amaze.ttf` instead of `/fonts/amaze.ttf`.

   *Be aware that in order for the path `/assets/fonts/amaze.ttf` to work you would need to put the `amaze.ttf` font in `/app/assets/fonts/fonts/` or `/vendor/assets/fonts/fonts/`. The double `fonts` directory ensures there is a `fonts` directory in `/public/assets` after the assets are compiled. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29475775/293280) for more info.*
2. **Move your `fonts` directory to your `public` directory:**

   Since the requested path doesn't utilize the Asset Pipeline anyway, you can simply move your `fonts` directory to the `/public/` directory and the web server will automatically serve it. So your font(s) should be located at `/public/fonts/amaze.ttf`, etc.

That should do it!

Comment: As a workaround, putting `fonts/` in `public` serves me well for the moment. Must dig a little more later to put them back to `assets/` but now that the deadline draws near... I will leave them there

Comment: @FaithReaper Thanks for confirming that putting them in the public directory works.

Comment: I wrote the font file name (e.g. ```amaze.ttf```) without giving the path alongside the name, and it worked for me. My fonts are placed inside ```assets/fonts/```

Answer (score 4):

I have also face this problem with font-awesome but it is my general research for fonts.

I create a new directory under app/assets , named fonts. Then copy all the Fonts there and include it to the assets in **application.rb** file , like this :

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

rename your font-awesome.css to font-awesome.css.scss.erb and change the @font-face declaration in it like this

```
    @font-face { font-family: "FontAwesome"; src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot')%>'); 
src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix')%>') format('eot'), 
     url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.woff')%>') format('woff'), 
     url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.ttf')%>') format('truetype'), 
     url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome')%>') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
```

Hope this will helpful :)
There are more ref [Font-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313287/font-face-at-rails-4-0-with-sass-url-not-found-for-custom-fonts)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a file permission error, I had copied the files from another computer. once I fixed the permissions, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was as simple as my import in `application.scss` used `https//` instead of `https://` for the URL. Gotta read closely next time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.

I found a solution, why not put `fonts/*.ttf` into `app/assets/images/fonts/*.ttf` for dev env?

At the same time keep `config/environments/development.rb` still the default `config.serve_static_assets = false` false value.

This works for me.