# Getting Katex fonts to load with Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, asset-pipeline, katex

I'm integrating the [Katex](http://khan.github.io/KaTeX/) math formula rendering library into a Rails 3.2 app but the font assets keep returning a 404 error message:

```bash
Started GET "/assets/fonts/KaTeX_Math-Italic.woff"
Served asset /fonts/KaTeX_Math-Italic.woff - 404 Not Found (3ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/fonts/KaTeX_Math-Italic.woff"):
```

I placed all of the fonts in the `vendor/assets/fonts` directory.

Without manipulating the third party JS or CSS files, how do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that all of the assets are compiled into the `public/assets` directory instead of being separated like `public/assets/fonts`, which is what Katex is expecting.

However, subdirectories of these "main" directories *are* retained so I moved the Katex fonts to the following directory instead:

```
vendor/assets/fonts/fonts/
```

Now the `public/assets` directory contains a `fonts` directory and the path `/assets/fonts/KaTeX_Math-Italic.woff` gets served just fine.

I don't like having a `fonts/fonts` directory so let me know if there's a more elegant way to solve this that **doesn't** involve manipulating the third party JS or CSS assets.

Comment: Just put `fonts/*.ttf` into `app/assets/images/fonts/*.ttf` for dev env.

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've made the [katex](https://github.com/glebm/katex-ruby) gem works with Rails.
It also provides server-side rendering (via ExecJS).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. `/fonts/fonts` works for me but still have another problem when I refresh page, the fonts suddenly disappear and appear again.

I found a solution, why not put `fonts/*.ttf` into `app/assets/images/fonts/*.ttf` for dev env?

At the same time keep `config/environments/development.rb` still the default `config.serve_static_assets = false` false value.

This works for me.